# Build War with multi module project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a multi module maven project with three different modules Module-Data, Module-Domain, Module-Web. All three projects are spring boot projects, however Module-Web is the web component of the project that handles everything web oriented which I want to build a war file for. I have a parent project with the following pom file which contains no code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.somename</groupId>
<artifactId>My-Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>module-data</module>
    <module>module-domain</module>
    <module>modele-web</module>
</modules>
```

Module-Domain depends on Module-Data and Module-Web depends on both Module-Data and Module-Domain. The problem I'm having is that when I try to build the project using maven it fails when building the Module-Domain with the following erros:

```
package com.somename.data.model does not exist // class file with this error
```

Module-Domain class files that imports from the Module-Data project fails with this error. I suspect this is because maven is not adding the Module-Data jar to the Module-Domain when building although its referenced in its pom file. How can I solve this problem and generate a war file with all dependencies?

Module-Domain pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somename.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Module-Web pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somename.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somename.domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-domain</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Verify if the version  0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is defined on each pom.xml. Because in the parent pom, you are defining the version 1.0-SNAPSHOT for all modules, unless you redefine it in the subprojects.
I mean, the version should match when you set up a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple straight-forward approach that you are using. Should not cause a problem.

Module-Domain pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somename</groupId>
    <artifactId>My-Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somename.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- Make sure this version is correct -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Module-Web pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somename</groupId>
    <artifactId>My-Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somename.domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-domain</artifactId> <!-- pulls "module-data" as well : transitive dependency -->
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- Make sure this version is correct -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Do **maven clean compile** on the parent project that would build all the modules.

If you still see any compilation issues, you would need fix the source code.